# можно ли использовать Вызвать метод Объявленный в другом методе?

Tags: c#, unity3d, методы

Зарасти У меня метод

```
turnOnLeftColorPaths(randomVectors3LeftpathIndex);
```

объявлен внутри метода void Start();
можно ли вызвать метод "turnOnLeftColorPaths" вне метода "Start" (в другом методе) ?

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Только если передать его туда как делегат.

Comment: так Интересно... Спасибо